# Does cyclone (python) support HTTPS connections and SSL?

Tags: python, ssl, https, cyclone

Does cyclone (python) support HTTPS connections and SSL?  If so, can you please provide an example?

I've looked through the documentation and code on the [cyclone github page](https://github.com/fiorix/cyclone/), and can't find any reference to SSL.  But since lots of cyclone is just wrapping twisted, maybe there's something I'm missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/fiorix/cyclone/#readme):

> cyclone is a Twisted protocol, therefore it may be used in conjunction
>   with any other protocol implemented in Twisted.

If Twisted supports SSL then cyclone supports it e.g.:

```
#file: cyclone-ssl.py
import cyclone.web

class IndexHandler(cyclone.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("hello world")

factory = cyclone.web.Application([(r"/", IndexHandler)])
portstr = "ssl:4443:privateKey=server_key.pem:certKey=server_cert.pem"

# make twisted app
from twisted.application import service, strports

application = service.Application("cyclone-ssl")
strports.service(portstr, factory).setServiceParent(application)
```

Run it as:

```
$ twistd -ny cyclone-ssl.py
```

The part that activates ssl is `portstr`. It specifies that the server serves on `4443` port and uses `server_key.pem` as its private key, `server_cert.pem` as a certificate.

Answer (score 4):

SSL examples have been added after I found this post. It's here: https://github.com/fiorix/cyclone/tree/master/demos/ssl